# How to embed a salesforce marketing cloud microsite in 3rd party website page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, microsites

**QUESTION:** I have a microsite (web page) with some fields on it that I am submitting / saving in a data extension. With the help of triggered send, I am sending an email to the user that is being added to the data extension (when a user submits the form).

With the help of AMScript, I am populating the record to the data extension.

**PROBLEM:** The microsite (web page) is only available via a URL (something like:  http://pages.abc.companyname.com/.....pagename....)

•   Is there any way, I can embed a microsite on 3rd party site(s)? So that whole form/content of the microsite page is available on one of our websites?

•   Is there any way, I can eliminate the form page which is my microsite (with fields) and use a 3rd party webpage to send (or pass) the values to the fields directly via API and accomplish the same results?

Answer (score 4):

Yes and yes.

You can use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to embed a SFMC Microsite page in a 3rd party site.

Also, you can use the [FuelSDK](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/) and write API calls (or use your own implementation of the SFMC SOAP or REST API) to populate Data Extension rows and fire off triggered emails.

Comment: (1) Regarding embedding - Is there any other approach apart from iframe? iframe is not the best technique (not mobile friendly) and it's a workaround not a solution. (2) Do you have any working example (with code & steps to follow)?

Comment: (1) The FuelSDK option I mentioned doesn't use an iframe.  (2) No, but perhaps you can give it a shot and if necessary, post another question with details about where you're stuck..