# Use Cloud page directly on a website?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

Is it possible to integrate SFMC Cloudpages (Landing Page or Smartcapture form) directly inside a website to create - for example - a preference center on the user account?

If yes, what would be the technical requirements?

Comment: You can use Cloud Page URL in your website as link or button. when user clicks on the URL it will take them to preference center which is your MC cloud page.

Comment: OK. So it is impossible to integrate a Landing Page or Smartcapture form in an iframe on a website, and passing parameters from the user account directly in the form and in the targeted DE ?

Comment: You can do It. follow this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121468/how-to-embed-a-salesforce-marketing-cloud-microsite-in-3rd-party-website-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to follow a [headless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_content_management_system) approach to this :-)

How I have done this before is by building JSON [code resources](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_code_resource.htm&type=5) in Cloud Pages, exposing the data from SFMC in a way allowing it to be fetched, parsed and committed using JS. Let's follow an example:

1. You build a page on your existing website: www.example.com/preferences
2. When building a preference center link in your email, you would append a (preferably hashed) ID of the subscriber to the url: www.example.com/preferences?id=a87bf704318047114bb922b66d443748
3. Javascript on your page will call the code resource on SFMC, providing the hashed ID
4. Code resource will lookup (using Ampscript) the subscriber based on the hashed value, and return personal information, preferences, subscriptions etc. - fetching it from a number of data extensions, and outputting it in JSON format.
5. JS parses the JSON, outputting the data into the DOM, into e.g. form fields
6. Once updated, the subscriber submits the form, and the data is sent to another code resource, which uses ampscript to upsert to the appropriate data extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the cloud page as a [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to embed the preference page within a website. There would be rendering/design issues that you would need to think about when doing this though. As if the preference page is too long you can have double scroll bars which isn't the best ux design on a page.